# Starting activity from alarm broadcast receiver even when user clicked home button

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, start-activity

I'm searching whole day how to do this in my opinion simple task...i have an alarm in my app and when it goes off i want to bring my app in front of the user screen so he can turn the alarm off...
In my activity i have set up an intent to call the reciever...

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("sample") );
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( MapActivity.this, 0, new Intent("sample"),0 );
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(MapActivity.this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
```

and this is my onRecieve method

```
@Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm time has been reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Uri notifikacijaAlarma = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    final Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notifikacijaAlarma);
    r.play();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "TRAININGCOUNDOWN");
    wl.acquire();

    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), GlavniIzbornik.class);
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);

    startActivity(i);
    wl.release();

}
```

so my alarm goes off even when i go to another application or do anything else on the phone...it shows Toast and plays the ringtone but it doesn't bring my app to front and when i manually go to my app it starts activity but i just can't get it so it will bring my app to front.

does anyone have some suggestion about this?

PS i know i should play ringtone from my alarm activity...i just wanted to see if the whole code gets executed...

Comment: wow, thanks man...it finally works...i can't tell you how much i've spend on this problem...

Comment: thanks man...i didn't see place to tick the rigght answer but now i did it... :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Enjoy your stay, and I hope you learn a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting the `Activity` by an explicit `Intent`. Delete lines `i.setAction(...)` and `i.setCategory(...)`. These are used in manifest to show this `Activity` in launcher.

Next according to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) you do not set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` yourself.

Do not **EVER** use `getBaseContext()`, in `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(...)` use `context` as in `new Intent(context, GlavniIzbornik.class);` or `context.startActivity(i)`. In `Activity` or `Service` use `this`.